# Where on the date palm tree does the lulav come from?

Tags: sukkah, agriculture, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, chagim-holidays

Having looked at a number of date palms I cannot seem to locate where the closed fronds (lulav) on the date palms actually are.

The majority of fronds that are visible on a date palm have open/dispersed leaves. Where on the date palm tree are the closed fronds located and does each date palm only have one lulav or several?

(Answers containing diagrams would be most helpful)

Comment: Pretty sure its when the 'leaves' are young, before they sprout open.

Comment: It'd be easier to see them if you had wings.

Comment: Touche. I was actually on a balcony the other day looking down upon some date palms

Comment: @user6591 [ברוך שכוונתי](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/46141/5323) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a picture (linked from [here](http://hamafitzesrogim.com/igallery/category/view/id/2/)). There are several per tree.

[Picture http://hamafitzesrogim.com/media/igallery/u/n/untitled_event_-_10_1.jpg](http://hamafitzesrogim.com/media/igallery/u/n/untitled_event_-_10_1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, what you saw as "open/dispersed leaves" were, at one point, closed *lulavim* that later spread out.

כך שמעתי.

Comment: נפרצו עליו פסול

Comment: @DoubleAA [Correct](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=29b&format=pdf). So?